# Formatting variable of type double when declaring it

Tags: java, math, rounding, decimalformat, decimal-point

I'm aware of the many ways of formatting a double variable to X # of decimal places. With that being said:

```
static double currentSelectedPrice = 0.00; //format to 2 decimal places
static double usercashBalance = 0.00
```

The code below is found at different locations through my code. I do not want to go through the code and format the result of `(currentSelectedPrice - usercashBalance)`

```
if(usercashBalance < currentSelectedPrice)                
{
      System.out.println("Remaing: $" + (currentSelectedPrice - usercashBalance));
      continue;
}
```

It would be ideal to already have those variables formatted when declaring them (so the output of its operations is also formatted).
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

A `double` (or `Double`) has no formatting information!

It is just a floating point representation of a value.

These two lines result in identical values for `d`:

```
double d = 1;
double d = 1.00000000;
```

You can however control how a double is rendered/formatted, eg

```
String formatted = String.format("%,.4f", d);
```

Renders the double value with 4 decimal places.

---

Tip: if you store all currency values as an `int` of cents, and render it as decimal dollars, most of your problems disappear.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't thought of formatting the output.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this

```
if(usercashBalance < currentSelectedPrice)                
{
    System.out.printf("Remaing: $%.<x>f", (currentSelectedPrice - usercashBalance));
    continue;
}
```

x indicating the number of decimals you want to print from your result